# Behat/Mink - trouble finding buttons

Tags: xpath, behat, mink

My application under test has been developed by external suppliers so I have no control over the HTML structure. The application is extremely Javascript and Ajax heavy, with numerous dynamically generated buttons and auto-complete lists.

In other words, the characteristics of the pages are that they are filled with:

- Elements with no fixed IDs (IDs are generated on the fly and have
  numbers or other text dynamically added to them)
- The same happens with some classes
- Most of the times the buttons have no text associated with them since they are either custom coded 'down' arrows for lookup lists
  (which aren't lookup lists but hidden divs) or '+' and '-' icons to
  maximise or minimise portions of the content. -

It is therefore very difficult to identify these elements, especially the buttons.

I am trying to write a generic 'I click on the button near y' type of step so that it is not necessary to hardcode each and every button (assuming I can even get something to identify them with) into each and every test.

The thinking behind this is that normally there is a label of some sort close to the button at least.

What I want to to is to find the text label, then see if there is a button inside the same scope, and if there is not, move 'back' through the parent elements, and check if there is a button inside the scope of each parent level, up to 5 parents.

There might be all sorts of problems with this approach but I am just curious to see if this will work in general. I have run into some problems.

First I tried to use Xpaths, so I got the Xpath of the parent through :

```
$parentelement = $element->getParent();

$parentXpath->getXpath();
```

This would give me an Xpath of : `(//html//span[text()='Cost center'])[1]` and moving up through the parent elements all the time, they would become successively:

```
(//html//span[text()='Cost center'])[1]/..[1]

(//html//span[text()='Cost center'])[1]/..[1]/..[1]
```

and so forth.

The actual button is located in: `(//html//span[text()='Cost center'])[1]/..[1]/..[1]//button` but it has to go through all the parent elements in order to get there, so it will start with `(//html//span[text()='Cost center'])[1]//button` and should end with `(//html//span[text()='Cost center'])[1]/..[1]/..[1]//button` where it should find the button.

Trying to use Xpath I used:

```
$button_element = $session->getPage()->find('xpath',$parentXpath."//button")
```

I soon saw that the 'find' command appends an //html to the front of your xpath string so the Xpath that it tried to use ended up being (for each parent Xpath, but using this one as an example):

```
(//html(//html//span[text()='Cost center'])[1]/..[1])
```

I then stripped out the brackets as well as the //html, leaving me with:

```
//span[text()='Cost center'][1]/..[1]
```

but when I tried:

```
$button_element = $session->getPage()->find('xpath',$strippedParentXpath."//button")
```

I got the following error:

```
SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string '(//html//span[text()='Cost center'][1]/..[1]//button)[1]' is not a valid XPath expression
```

However, Firepath can execute this expression and does not show a syntax error for it, although it does not find the actual button (since the button is actually located one level up, where Firepath DOES find it).

So my question 1 is: What is wrong with my Xpath that I can't use it in the find? It actually looks as if `//span[text()='Cost center'][1]//button` does not throw the same exception, since as I said, I am looping through the parent Xpaths, and it starts with `//span[text()='Cost center'][1]//button`. It crashes on `//span[text()='Cost center'][1]/..[1]//button`.

My second option was to get the parent element each time, starting with finding the text on the page, but then to search for a button inside the scope of the parent element using the findbutton functionality.

Looping through the parent elements (up to a maximum of 5):

```
$parentelement = $parentelement->getParent();

$butonelement = $parentelement->findbutton('xxx');
```

In other words, find ANY button in the scope of the parent element. The problem I have is how to specify a generic 'button'.

One has to associate SOME text with the button (depicted by the 'xxx' above).

But this is a typical example of buttons in the application:

```
<button class="autocomplete_button" type="button" id="button_OM_1">&nbsp;</button>
```

Where the class is used more than once, and the ID is auto-generated and not the same number all the time. There is no text associated with the button since the class specifies an image.

Question 2: So how can I use 'findbutton' to generically find a 'button' no specific distinguishing characteristics? Please note that I actually did try findbutton("button"), taking the chance that there might be a 'button' somewhere in a button, but this did not work either. At least, it doesn't work consistently and by that I mean that the same test randomly seems to either find or not find the same button when I run the test a couple of times.

Comment: Side note on this: don't use `alt` for `button`s - it won't work, despite the DocBlock suggesting it will. Use `title` or something else. I spent way too long working this out.

Answer (score 1):

After doing some more investigation on this issue I have found the following:
My method of trying to find the closest button to a piece of text via traversing 'up' through the scope of the divs and spans around the text (using xpath) is actually working.

What is NOT working is SAHI, which I am using as the web driver. In other words, it is not a Behat/Mink problem, it is SAHI specific issue.

I tried the same code using Selenium2 and it executes perfectly.

I still require an answer to question 2 - how can I use findbutton() without a specific parameter such as the ID, name or value but I will see if I can find an answer to that question separately and on the Behat user group since I do think that is a Behat/Mink specific issue.

Comment: Do you have a label associated with the button?

Answer (score 0):

I normaly use css selector and with that, I use to navigate to the class and ID's that the button is inside.
 it is easier than xpath I think, like you can use

```
 $this->getSession ()->getPage ()->find ( 'css', '.parrent1 .parrent2 .autocomplete_button ' );
```

I think this will help you as you know which button  your gonna use in each scenario

Comment: Thanks for the feedback but I am not sure we are on the same page. I don't actually know the class or the ID of the button OR the parent element since these are normally dynamically generated on the fly with javascript. In the mean time I have done some more investigation around why my Xpath method does not want to work and I have an answer which I am posting below.